# php update database when checkbox is clicked

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am displaying data from database and I would like to refresh the results when a user clicks on specific checkbox.

I have set the name attribute to the checkbox and tried to use `isset` but that couldn't work  as I actually don't have a form and displaying results on the same page using pagination. How do I load new results when checkbox is clicked without using `<form>`?

Here is the javascript that I used to get the page refreshed(not results)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var reloading;

    function checkReloading() {
        if ( window.location.hash == "#autoreload" ) {
            reloading=setTimeout("window.location.reload();", 100);
            document.getElementById("reloadCB").checked=true;
        }
    }

    function toggleAutoRefresh( cb ) {
        if ( cb.checked ) {
            window.location.replace("#autoreload");
            reloading=setTimeout("window.location.reload();", 100);
        } else {
            window.location.replace("#");
            clearTimeout( reloading );
        }
    }

    window.onload=checkReloading;
</script>
```

and here is the php first I tried `$_POST` to check if the checkbox is selected but that couldn't work and I also tried `$_GET` and again the same thing. The problem is that the below code shows results from table two ignoring table one even if checkbox is selected.

```
try {    
    if ( isset( $_GET["size"] ) ) {
        $paginate = new pagination($page, 'SELECT * FROM test1 ORDER BY id desc', $options); exit();    
} else { 
        $paginate = new pagination($page, 'SELECT * FROM test2 ORDER BY id desc', $options);    
}
} catch( paginationException $e ) {
    echo $e;
    exit();
}
```

The html

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="size" onclick="toggleAutoRefresh(this);" id="reloadCB">
```

Comment: at which point is the form submission happening? It looks to me like you are not actually submitting any data (just refreshing the page) to the server which is why it always selects from test2.

Comment: No get parameters are passed to the script. You have to change the `window.location` to include e.g. `?size=1`. Or wrap the checkbox in a form and have the form submit in `toggleAutoRefresh`

Comment: I have no form. I am just displaying the data from the table and would like to use checkbox update the results.4

Comment: Then you need to pass the size value to the php script which you are not doing here.

Comment: @milkshake I know that's what I am not doing. is there any other way to pass the size value?

Comment: you need to submit the form to get the data in php - lookup submit() in jquery http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could try this:

```
function toggleAutoRefresh( cb ) {
    if ( cb.checked ) {
        window.location.replace("#autoreload");
        reloading=setTimeout(function(){
            // get the current url and append the parameter
            var url = window.location.href + "?size=1";
            window.open(url, '_self'); //open url
            }, 100);
    } else {
        window.location.replace("#");
        clearTimeout( reloading );
    }
}
```

hope this helps.

**Edited to include second perimeter to window.open**

Comment: @user2510039 ok add `'_self'` as a second parameter in the window.open() function and see if that fixes it.